# Easiest Way to read a xls File with PHP

Tags: php, excel, webserver

I got a xls file on a hosted Webserver and now I am trying to read it with PHP. It is not important to read the whole file. I just need a few cell information to work with them. So what is the best way to do that?

Comment: A pure PHP library for reading and writing spreadsheet files - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet . Visit the Docs at https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/

You could also work with certain columns trough Read Filters available in the library -

Answer (score -1):

```
//Try PHP-ExcelReader     

<?php
        include 'excel_reader.php';       // include the class
        $excel = new PhpExcelReader;      // creates object instance of the class
        $excel->read('excel_file.xls');   // reads and stores the excel file data

        // Test to see the excel data stored in $sheets property
        echo '<pre>';
        var_export($excel->sheets);

        echo '</pre>';

        or 

     echo '<pre>';
        print_r($excel->sheets);

        echo '</pre>';
```